# Cannot serve files from Localhost on MacOs Ventura

Tags: apache, localhost, mamp

I have set up Homebrew, Php, MySql and Apache all ok and running on Ventura 13.3 no problems

However I want to serve files from /Library/WebServer/Documents rather than ~sites folder and have added following to httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

But I get this error:

*This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.*

What is the issue here?

Comment: I've been getting the same problem since I upgraded to 13.4 and I cannot find anything online that addresses it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your /etc/hosts file.
Change 127.0.0.1 with your ip address (you could get it by running `ipconfig getifaddr en0` in your terminal).
Then run `ping localhost` and you should see your ip address.
Try to run your localhost and it should work.